# How to validate Ansible playbook from azure yaml build file?

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, azure-pipelines-yaml

How can we validate the Ansible Playbook from yaml build file  ? Yamllint ?

Answer (score 0):

Yamlint is installed in Ubuntu and Linux Azure agents as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software)

So you can run `yamlint` inside a [bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) so as to check your yml files. Choose whatever parameters that suit you.

You can run this pipeline as a [build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation), so that no branch is merged into main without validation.